# Three strings of code repeat in three different view-functios

Tags: python-3.x, django, function, view, utility

I have three view-functions in views.py in django project that using a same three arguments in them:

```
paginator = Paginator(post_list, settings.POSTS_LIMIT)
page_number = request.GET.get('page')
page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
```

How can I put em in a single function (make an utility) to use one string of code in my view-functions, instead of repeat using three?
Thats my first question here, thank you :)

Comment: This is the main reason to use a class-based view: because the pagination is encapsulated into a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note, you can create a single function to handle this, taking the info it needs as arguments.  You can include this as a helper function in your views.py or separate it out into a utils.py and then import it. Assuming the latter, for tidiness and future-proofing

utils.py

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.conf.settings import POSTS_LIMITS #you may have another place for your settings
from .utils import make_pagination #utils.py file in same directory

def make_pagination(request, thing_to_paginate, num_per_page=POSTS_LIMITS)
    paginator = Paginator(thing_to_paginate, num_per_page)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return page_obj
```

views.py

```
from .utils import make_pagination

def records(request):
   ...
   #we'll use the provided settings-based default for num_per_page
   page_obj = make_pagination(request, post_list)
   return render(request, 'template.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})
```

If you wanted more than just the page_obj for some reason, you can return more than the one value, eg,

utils.py

```
...
return page_obj, paginator
```

views py

```
...
page_obj, paginator = make_pagination(request, post_list)
```

I've gotten the page number in the function itself, but you can also do that either in the view itself, or even in the function call in the view eg,

```
make_pagination(request.GET.get('page') or 1, post_list)
```

(If you go this path, don't forget to change the function to accommodate the different argument)

Comment: thanks! that was helpful. But how can i use make_pagination without request? My reviewer said that i can use just page_number instrad of request.

Comment: But how can i def make_pagination(post_list, page_number), when i need a request.GET.get(‘page’)?

Comment: Sorry, I had misread something and included an unnecessary element in the function arguments.  I've updated the answer to correct this.  You will need to get the page number from request at some point. I've done this within the new function but you can also do that either in the view itself, or even in the function call eg, make_pagination(request.GET.get('page') or 1, post_list).

Comment: All works well! Thanks!